# Walmart Paginated Products API

Tags: walmart-api

I am attempting to use the Paginated Products API to make a GET request using the optional `specialOffer` parameter. I have made many requests with multiple variations of the parameters available and have received an empty JSON object for each request whenever I use the `specialOffer` parameter. However, when I use the other optional parameters available without the `specialOffer` parameter, such as `category`, `brand`, `format`, and `count`, I receive the expected response.

Example requests that returns empty JSON object:

`http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/paginated/items?apiKey=APIKEY&specialOffer=specialBuy`

`http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/paginated/items?apiKey=APIKEY&category=3944_1060825_1939756&specialOffer=specialBuy&count=10`

Example request that returns expected results:

`http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/paginated/items?apiKey=APIKEY&category=3944_1060825_1939756&count=10`

In addition to this, I have ensured that there are items available which are in the `specialBuy` (as well as `rollback` and `clearance`) categories, by checking the Special Feeds like so:
`http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/feeds/specialbuy?apikey=APIKEY&categoryId=3944_1060825_1939756`

Documentation for the Paginated Products API:

https://developer.walmartlabs.com/docs/read/Paginated_Products_API

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?